# Repeat Dates and Roles using Column Dates from (E to I)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I have some Data where, there are 8 columns. I want to keep Column, B,E,F,G,H and I.

In Column B I have Some positions and in other columns E,F,G,H and I  i have dates. I want to convert the dates as 1 to count the Roles, to know that how many times the date is repeated in "Headers" for the "Roles".

I would really appreciate the help if it can be achieved using formula.

**DATA**

[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1inODg164A60TzW01iaQVfHGIO4QsuCtAleOyYurGTOU/edit#gid=910138630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I19), 
 E4:I19&"×"&B4:B19&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 5)&"×"&ROW(B4:B19), )), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2,Col4 
  pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

Comment: Is it possible to add Grand total in the end of the Last Row.